# Vim: How to indent html code correctly in php file?

Tags: vim, php, html

In php file :

```
<?php
...
?>
<html>

</html>
```

I could not indent the html source code with operator `=`.

How could I indent it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My workaround for this is to temporarily switch to html mode, mark region and indent, and then go back to php mode.

```
:set filetype=html
" mark html code
=
:set filetype=php
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an entry on the [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/) that details how to enable indenting of both PHP and HTML areas of PHP files: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Better_indent_support_for_php_with_html

Answer (score 0):

i added this to vimrc

```
au BufEnter,BufNew *.php :set filetype=html
```