# How to re-indent HTML snippets in vim?

Tags: html, vim

I'm aware of `tidy` for re-indenting an entire HTML page, but I work with templates and often want to re-indent just parts of an HTML document from vim.  I can't see an example of how to do this natively with vim and I don't see how I can do this with tidy, since it tries to insert "missing" head tags etc.  All I want is tags to be re-indented.  Could someone point me towards a command line utility which re-indents HTML snippets so that I can tweak my .vimrc to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To re-indent parts of an HTML document, select them in visual mode and use the `=` command:

```
={motion}    Filter {motion} lines through the external program
             given with the 'equalprg' option.
```

To re-indent the whole file you can type `gg=G` (go to first line, filter until the last line).

Comment: In e.g. PHP files Vim is also often confused about which parts are PHP and which are HTML. As in this case, it might be needed to explicitly set the `filetype` to HTML for Vim to understand and use its HTML indenting rules, so: 1. `:set ft=html`, 2. `V` for visual line select and 3. `=` for re-indenting should work no matter how Vim originally identified the file. `:set ft` can also be used to generally switch between auto-indentation rules for different languages combined in a single file, which often is the case with templating languages. See <http://superuser.com/q/189982/49184>